# Код срабатывает через раз. Выдаёт ошибку чтения

Tags: c++

Начал изучать c++. Делал задание из книжки Страуструпа. Суть в том, чтобы задать указатель в цикле так, чтобы условие внутри цикла принимало вид (*p=='?'). Код работает исправно, но через раз. Иногда выдаёт ошибку чтения файла. В чём может быть проблема?

```
int main(){
char* p;
char m[4] = {'E', '?', '4', '?'};
p = m;
int i=0;
while (*p++ != '0') {
    if (*p == '?') {
        i++;
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Массив `char m[4] = {'E', '?', '4', '?'};` не заканчивается нулем. А в цикле по переменной p вы перебираете до нулевого элемента ...

Comment: И, кстати, вы начинаете сравнение сразу для второго символа массива, так что если бы вместо `'E'` был `'?'` — вы бы его не учли...